# Uninstalling WinXP while keeping Ubuntu14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, uninstall, windows-xp

I have been using Windows XP and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I want to uninstall/remove Windows XP.

I have some doubts, please help to resolve them.

- If I do so what will happen to NTFS partitions?
- Can I use them from Ubuntu after removing Windows?
- Do I need to mount them first on Ubuntu before removing Windows XP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want, you can continue to use NTFS partitions from Ubuntu -- I've got a 1 TB drive that contains *seven* NTFS partitions that I've never gotten around to converting, even though the WinXP installed there hasn't been bootable in years.  If the amount of storage is small enough for practicality, however, I'd recommend converting the old Windows partitions to a more reliable storage format (my own preference is ext4, because its journaling greatly improves the odds of an event-free recovery if you have an unexpected shutdown, for instance due to a power drop).

Obviously, you need to start by copying any data you want to keep from the NTFS partitions to storage you won't be erasing; you should also make a complete backup of your Ubuntu installation, just in case of mistakes.

The simplest way to uninstall XP in your situation is to use Ubuntu disk management tools (`gparted`, for instance) to delete and replace the partition(s) occupied by Windows, or reformat those partitions to a more Linux-friendly filesystem (such as ext4, or at least FAT32 if you need to maintain compatibility with Windows for some reason).  The NTFS partitions will need to be unmounted to make partition changes (`gparted` offers this function), and removing the old partitions gives the option to combined them or use the freed space to expand an adjacent Ubuntu partition (such as /home or /).

If you prefer to continue to use the NTFS partitions for storage, you can shortcut this by simply erasing the entire /windows directory tree (this will get you back a couple GB of storage) and anything that contains stored Windows Update files.  Windows XP (through at least Vista and 7) however, has a bad habit of stashing stuff in other folders that may not be obviously part of Windows, which is part of why I recommend reformatting those partitions (at a minimum).

Once you're done with any partitions changes, you'll need to update your `/etc/fstab` to reflect the new UUID of the reformatted or recreated partition(s), else you'll get errors during boot.  Following this, you'll need to update your GRUB to reflect that there is no longer a Windows option.  Once that's done, Windows will be eradicated from your computer and you'll be ready to live a pure life (at least at home).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. This is helpful. I have 4TB drive. I wish to continue NTFS partitions as they are.